# Filter the URL of next_posts_link & previous_posts_link

Tags: filters, hooks, language, plugin-qtranslate

I am working with the [qTranslate plugin](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) to create a multi-lingual website. The plugin does a great job of translation except for on the `next_posts_link` & `previous_posts_link` template tags.

When a user has selected a different language the URL should change from:

http://mysite.com/test/page/2 (for default language)

to

http://mysite.com/fr/test/page/2 (for french language)

The plugin provides functions for modification/translation of URLs using the  `qtrans_convertURL($url)` function. The problem I am having is finding a suitable hook or filter that will allow me to modify the URL output by the next_posts_link & previous_posts_link template tags.

The closest two WordPress filters I have found are:

```
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'my_next_attr');
add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'my_prev_attr');
```

Any tips would be most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful tip from @t31os the issue can be fixed with the following code:

```
/***************************************************************
* Function qtranslate_next_previous_fix
* Ensure that the URL for next_posts_link & previous_posts_link work with qTranslate
***************************************************************/

add_filter('get_pagenum_link', 'qtranslate_next_previous_fix');

function qtranslate_next_previous_fix($url) {
    return qtrans_convertURL($url);
}
```

This fix works for custom post types too.

**Updated**

This second function ensures that the `next_post_link` & `previous_post_link` template tags are also filtered correctly on custom post types.

```
/***************************************************************
* Function qtranslate_single_next_previous_fix
* Ensure that the URL for next_post_link & previous_post_link work with qTranslate
***************************************************************/

add_filter('next_post_link', 'qtranslate_single_next_previous_fix');
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'qtranslate_single_next_previous_fix');

function qtranslate_single_next_previous_fix($url) {
    $just_url = preg_match("/href=\"([^\"]*)\"/", $url, $matches);
    return str_replace($matches[1], qtrans_convertURL($matches[1]), $url);
}
```

Comment: I think you have your args/priority mixed up there, `1` would represent the priority and `9999` the callback function's number of supported args(perhaps intended to be the other way round?).. ;)

Comment: Still getting to grips with those! I have removed them from the code as it works without.

Answer (score 4):

Run a filter on `get_pagenum_link` and you should be able to do what you want.

The `next_posts_link` / `previous_posts_link` functions each call functions that in turn call other functions, which eventually route back to the `get_pagenum_link` function which provides a filter by the same name.

It should give you the control you need, though post a comment if you specifically need an example.

For the singular post link functions, ie. `next_post_link` / `previous_post_link` (note the non-plural other readers) there's a filter hook with a matching name, eg. `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link`..

Comment: Many thanks. This filter worked perfectly. Code added above for others who face a similar problem.

Comment: @t31os Do you know of a similar filter for `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link` as these both too suffer from the same issue?

Comment: See updated answer... ;)

Comment: @t31os Brilliant. I have updated my answer with a second filter. Thanks again.